# How can I condense a .configure in TKinter down to one command?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a program which will use multiple menus and buttons, and to make the menus quick (and as I am not very proficient with Tkinter) I have used PAGE to generate some code for me. However, it outputs a very lengthy set of .configure statements for each button, meaning my project now totals over 1400 lines of code- and I'm not even halfway done yet. Is there a way I can turn all of these .configure commands into one? I have included a sample of my code below for reference.

```
self.Button7 = Button(top)
self.Button7.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.76, height=24, width=257)
self.Button7.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
self.Button7.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
self.Button7.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
self.Button7.configure(command=root.destroy)
self.Button7.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
self.Button7.configure(foreground="#000000")
self.Button7.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
self.Button7.configure(highlightcolor="black")
self.Button7.configure(pady="0")
self.Button7.configure(text='''Go back''')
```

Comment: What is "PAGE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `dictionary` of the arguments that need to be passed for configuration and then use the [argument unpacking magic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/131415/106810) `**`, like below.

```
my_config = {
    'foreground': "#000000",
    'background': "#d9d9d9",
    # ...
}
self.Button7.configure(**my_config)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them all in a single command:

```
self.Button7.configure(foreground="#000000", highlightbackground="#d9d9d9", highlightcolor="black", etc)
```

But why would you want to? It's much neater to do it your way.

Comment: And you don't even need to use ``.configure()`` at all - the same keywords work directly in the ``Button()`` constructor.